# Get Value of Radio button with a Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created two radio buttons. The radio buttons have a background image. 
One checked and one unchecked image. I use CSS to change the images back and forth.

Both the radio buttons have values. I'm trying to get the values for each radio button when checked. Can I do this without JavaScript? If not, how can I get the value of the radio button when it's checked?

```js
    var yesImg = document.getElementById('radio_one'); 
    var noImg = document.getElementById('radio_two');

    if (yesImg.src.match('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blueberry-basic/32/radio-button-on-icon.png')) {
    
        console.log(document.getElementById('find_val').value);
    }
    else if (noImg.src.match('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blueberry-basic/32/radio-button-on-icon.png')) {

        console.log(document.getElementById('find_val').value);
    }
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blueberry-basic/32/radio-button-off-icon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
 
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blueberry-basic/32/radio-button-on-icon.png');
}

.lbl-style{
   padding-left:30px;
   padding-top:8px;
}
```

```html
<span >                                       
 <input type="radio" id="radio_one" value="1" name="number" class="rdo-style"/>
 <label for="radio_one" class="lbl-style" >Value 1</label>
</span>



<span >
 <input type="radio" id="radio_two" value="2" name="number" class="rdo-style"/>
 <label for="radio_two" class="lbl-style" >Value 2</label>
</span>

<input type="hidden" id="find_val" name="number" />
```

Comment: You can't get a value from any element w/o script.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tips guys!